# Using Each Thread As Separate Publisher in Ros2 Node

Tags: c++, multithreading, ros, robotics, ros2

I am trying to make a node with multiple publisher in it and each publisher will be work own separate thread.

When I try to basic idea implementation gives me this error;

```
2022-07-02 13:14:16.757 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::GetParameters_Request_ -> Function registerType 
2022-07-02 13:14:16.758 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::GetParameterTypes_Request_ -> Function registerType 
2022-07-02 13:14:16.758 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::GetParameterTypes_Response_ -> Function registerType 
2022-07-02 13:14:16.759 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::SetParameters_Request_ -> Function registerType 2022-
07-02 13:14:16.759 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::SetParameters_Response_ -> Function registerType 2022-
07-02 13:14:16.760 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::SetParametersAtomically_Request_ -> Function registerType 
2022-07-02 13:14:16.762 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::ListParameters_Request_ -> Function registerType 2022-
07-02 13:14:16.762 [PARTICIPANT Error] Type with the same name already exists:rcl_interfaces::srv::dds_::ListParameters_Response_ -> Function registerType
```

My implementation;

Firstly making a basic Ros Node class to publishing data and then create 5 thread to make a publisher for each and their own stack. Using this Ros Node class. Then using rclcpp::spin(node) must be publish the data but it gives the above error.

```
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "example_interfaces/msg/string.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <thread>


class Publisher: public rclcpp::Node{

public:
    Publisher(std::string name, std::string _data) : Node(name), data(_data){
        publisher = this->create_publisher<example_interfaces::msg::String>("pub_topic", 10);
        timer = create_wall_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(555), std::bind(&Publisher::call_back, this));

    }

private:

    void call_back(){

        example_interfaces::msg::String msg;
        msg.data = data;
        publisher->publish(msg);
    }

    std::string data;
    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Publisher<example_interfaces::msg::String>> publisher;
    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::TimerBase> timer; 
 };

void thread_main(std::string data){

    std::shared_ptr<Publisher> node = std::make_shared<Publisher>(data , data);
    rclcpp::spin(node);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);

    std::vector<std::string> dataset{"first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"};
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(5);

    for(size_t i=0; i<dataset.size(); ++i){
        threads[i] = std::thread(thread_main, dataset.at(i));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){
        threads[i].join();
    }

    rclcpp::shutdown();

    return 0;
 }
```